# Best practices: extra methods in c++

Tags: c++, class, methods

So, I'm doing a project where I have a class named Window, and the goal of the class is storing the state of the window (whether the window is open or closed) and having a method Toggle, which toggles the window.

```
class Window {
 public:
  explicit Window(bool is_open);

  Window(const Window&) = default;
  Window& operator=(const Window&) = default;

  ~Window() {}

  // Returns if the window is open.
  bool is_open();

  // Toggles the window. Returns if the window is now open.
  bool Toggle();

 private:
  bool is_open_;
};
```

However, I've been thinking if the class should also have two methods called Open and Close, which do exactly what the names suggest. This methods would give me more control over the window's state, even that, for the purpose of the task, they are useless.

So, what is the best thing to do here? Should I give the extra methods to the class or shouldn't I?

Comment: That's a design decision so there's not going to be a definite answer. If you need them or will likely need them in the future, implement them. They both can be implemented in terms of `is_open` (which should be `const noexcept`) and `Toggle`.

Comment: [Feature creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep) is generally never good. Begin by making the code as simple and basic as possible, solving only the original problem. If new features are needed then you do another round of requirements gathering, analysis, design and implementation, but only once the original program or code is finished.

Comment: dont implement stuff you don't need. If you consider that you should document, test and debug any code, then any code you do not write is good code. Read about test driven development, in a nutshell they first write a test and then code that makes the test pass, but not more, and that "not more" is important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have run into "You Aren't Gonna Need It" ([YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)).

If you need those features later, you can build them later at about the same cost as building them now. But if you build them now, you might not need them later, in which case that effort will be wasted. (Not to mention the cost of maintaining that extra code.)

There is always a temptation to build them now, if they are elegant features, because implementing elegant features is fun. You must be aware of this motive and not be swayed by it.

In my opinion, there is one good reason (apart from fun and honing your skills) to build a feature you might not need, and that's when you can reasonably predict that *if* you do need it later, you'll need it urgently on short notice. It's the reason to take an afternoon packing up a good first aid kit.

Answer (score 3):

In c++ you can solve many problems using free functions without the need pollute the class with member functions that might not be needed or only required in certain circumstances.

You could have a function like this (maybe a better naming should be chosen):

```
template<typename T>
inline bool toggle_open_state(T &obj) {
  if( obj.is_open() ) {
    obj.close();
  } else {
    obj.open();
  }

  return obj.is_open();
}
```

That way you could reuse that function for any object that has the member functions `is_open`, `close`, and `open`.

This approach can be seen in the std library where containers only have the bare minimum of member functions that are required to manipulate the container, everything else is part of the e.g. `algorithm` header.

Those helper functions can be part of a separate header and you include those headers only when you need them.

Comment: So instead of "polluting" the class, you pollute the namespace. How is that an improvement?

Comment: @bitmask because if you move those functions to an own header, you only need to include them when needed. And you keep the interface of the class clean only having the essential functions. I'm not talking about whether the function itself is not needed at all (because then it also shouldn't be in a separate header), but if it is a useful functionality that is actually used, but should not be part of the class itself.

Comment: I see. The extra header is actually a good point although it also diminishes the degree of self-documentation of the class. But I concede that this is a question of preference and coding style. +1 then.